# Display half screen flickering Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, screen

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 half of the screen flickering and unresponsive. I've got to change the GRUB boot options and add `nomodeset` get it fixed. But, with this option, I can't change brightness and the performance of the VGA is not great.

Here is the output of `lshw`:

```
    sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:601d000000-601dffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 3
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=2560,1600
```

Update 1:

Here is a screenshot without nomodeset

[Desktop screenshot without nomodeset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRfd3.jpg)

Update 2:

i've upgrade to ubuntu 23.04 and still didnt fix it,
here are some more info while booting without "nomodeset" :

```
glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) (0x9a40)
    Version: 39488.1.8
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 15768MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.3~git2310060600.dcb764~oibaf~l (git-dcb764b 2023-10-06 lunar-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.3~git2310060600.dcb764~oibaf~l (git-dcb764b 2023-10-06 lunar-oi
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.3~git2310060600.dcb764~oibaf~l (git-dcb764b 2023-10-06 lunar-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

.

```
inxi -G
    Graphics:
      Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-UP4 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
      Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.8 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
        compositor: gnome-shell v: 44.3 driver: X: loaded: vesa
        unloaded: fbdev,modesetting dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution: 2560x1600~60Hz
      API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.3~git2310060600.dcb764~oibaf~l (git-dcb764b
        2023-10-06 lunar-oibaf-ppa) renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
```

.

```
dmesg | grep i915
[    6.036063] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    6.039251] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    6.039321] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    6.041462] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    6.042938] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[    6.051575] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_12.bin (v2.12)
[    6.185228] mei_pxp 0000:00:16.0-fbf6fcf1-96cf-4e2e-a6a6-1bab8cbe36b1: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_pxp_tee_component_ops [i915])
[    6.185408] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Protected Xe Path (PXP) protected content support initialized
[    7.286628] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_htotal (expected 2840, found 2720)
[    7.286637] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_hblank_end (expected 2840, found 2720)
[    7.286641] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_vtotal (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    7.286645] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_vblank_end (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    7.286649] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_htotal (expected 2840, found 2720)
[    7.286653] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_hblank_end (expected 2840, found 2720)
[    7.286658] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_vtotal (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    7.286662] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_vblank_end (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    7.286697] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 417 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_modeset_verify.c:219 verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    7.286894] Modules linked in: overlay bnep joydev ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt binfmt_misc ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec coretemp snd_hda_core xt_tcpudp snd_hwdep xt_conntrack snd_pcm kvm_intel nf_conntrack snd_seq_midi nf_defrag_ipv6 snd_seq_midi_event kvm nf_defrag_ipv4 snd_rawmidi irqbypass iwlmvm btusb crct10dif_pclmul btrtl polyval_clmulni btbcm mei_hdcp mei_pxp i915(+) polyval_generic nft_compat snd_seq mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 nf_tables aesni_intel libcrc32c btintel
[    7.287048] RIP: 0010:verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    7.287233]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    7.287394]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    7.287526]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    7.287660]  intel_modeset_verify_crtc+0x60/0x90 [i915]
[    7.287797]  intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x600/0x910 [i915]
[    7.287957]  intel_atomic_commit+0x3bc/0x410 [i915]
[    7.288177]  intel_initial_commit+0x192/0x230 [i915]
[    7.288343]  intel_modeset_init+0x2d/0xa0 [i915]
[    7.288489]  i915_driver_probe+0x14d/0x440 [i915]
[    7.288648]  i915_pci_probe+0xd0/0x170 [i915]
[    7.288808]  i915_pci_register_driver+0x23/0x30 [i915]
[    7.288927]  i915_init+0x34/0x120 [i915]
[    7.289060]  ? __pfx_init_module+0x10/0x10 [i915]
[    7.295156] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    7.298307] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    7.298569] i915 0000:00:02.0: Backlight is not disabled.
[    7.298596] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 500 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_display_power_well.c:831 assert_can_enable_dc6+0xb3/0x120 [i915]
[    7.298794] Modules linked in: overlay bnep joydev ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt binfmt_misc ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec coretemp snd_hda_core xt_tcpudp snd_hwdep xt_conntrack snd_pcm kvm_intel nf_conntrack snd_seq_midi nf_defrag_ipv6 snd_seq_midi_event kvm nf_defrag_ipv4 snd_rawmidi irqbypass iwlmvm btusb crct10dif_pclmul btrtl polyval_clmulni btbcm mei_hdcp mei_pxp i915 polyval_generic nft_compat snd_seq mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 nf_tables aesni_intel libcrc32c btintel
[    7.298955] RIP: 0010:assert_can_enable_dc6+0xb3/0x120 [i915]
[    7.299195]  ? assert_can_enable_dc6+0xb3/0x120 [i915]
[    7.299388]  ? assert_can_enable_dc6+0xb3/0x120 [i915]
[    7.299530]  skl_enable_dc6+0x14/0xb0 [i915]
[    7.299700]  gen9_dc_off_power_well_disable+0xb2/0xd0 [i915]
[    7.299810]  intel_power_well_disable+0x60/0x80 [i915]
[    7.299919]  intel_power_well_put+0x47/0xb0 [i915]
[    7.300024]  __intel_display_power_put_domain+0xed/0x1e0 [i915]
[    7.300158]  ? __intel_runtime_pm_get+0x32/0xa0 [i915]
[    7.300249]  release_async_put_domains+0x88/0x120 [i915]
[    7.300437]  intel_display_power_flush_work+0xc1/0xf0 [i915]
[    7.300552]  intel_dp_detect+0x39c/0x570 [i915]
[    7.300763]  intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x18/0x50 [i915]
[    7.301259] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    8.394641] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_htotal (expected 2842, found 2720)
[    8.394644] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_hblank_end (expected 2842, found 2720)
[    8.394645] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_hsync_start (expected 2762, found 1380)
[    8.394646] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_hsync_end (expected 2802, found 1400)
[    8.394647] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_vtotal (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    8.394647] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_vblank_end (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    8.394648] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_htotal (expected 2842, found 2720)
[    8.394649] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_hblank_end (expected 2842, found 2720)
[    8.394650] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_hsync_start (expected 2762, found 1380)
[    8.394650] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_hsync_end (expected 2802, found 1400)
[    8.394651] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_vtotal (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    8.394652] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_vblank_end (expected 1710, found 1800)
[    8.394653] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in pixel_rate (expected 291594, found 332418)
[    8.394654] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.pipe_mode.crtc_clock (expected 291594, found 332418)
[    8.394655] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* [CRTC:98:pipe A] mismatch in hw.adjusted_mode.crtc_clock (expected 291594, found 332418)
[    8.394679] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 500 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_modeset_verify.c:219 verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    8.394807] Modules linked in: af_alg overlay bnep joydev ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6_tables ip6t_rt binfmt_misc ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG nf_log_syslog nft_limit xt_limit xt_addrtype x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec coretemp snd_hda_core xt_tcpudp snd_hwdep xt_conntrack snd_pcm kvm_intel nf_conntrack snd_seq_midi nf_defrag_ipv6 snd_seq_midi_event kvm nf_defrag_ipv4 snd_rawmidi irqbypass iwlmvm btusb crct10dif_pclmul btrtl polyval_clmulni btbcm mei_hdcp mei_pxp i915 polyval_generic nft_compat snd_seq mac80211 ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 nf_tables aesni_intel libcrc32c
[    8.394874] RIP: 0010:verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    8.394991]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    8.395093]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    8.395180]  ? verify_crtc_state+0x48d/0x570 [i915]
[    8.395265]  intel_modeset_verify_crtc+0x60/0x90 [i915]
[    8.395349]  intel_atomic_commit_tail+0x600/0x910 [i915]
[    8.395445]  intel_atomic_commit+0x3bc/0x410 [i915]
[    8.395680]  intel_fbdev_set_par+0x1a/0x70 [i915]
[    8.395861]  intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x18/0x50 [i915]
[    8.416699] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
```

Comment: anyone can help or redirect me to a site that contain the fix ?

Comment: anyone can help or redirect me to a site that contain the fix ?